# how to set setNextFocusDown in TextArea

Tags: textarea, codenameone

I am try to use setNextFocusDown method in TextArea eg:
textArea.setNextFocusDown(nextTextField);
But in keyboard it does not show next button so how to set setNextFocusDown in TextArea ?

Answer (score 0):

This will only apply if you do it in the beginning and only for `TextArea` subclasses. Notice this hint will not apply for every case.